# Dreamweaver CC fluid grid div layout controls missing after reopening file

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver, fluid-layout

I am building a site using the fluid grid layout in Dreamweaver CC. I can add new fluid divs that have resize handles, move up/down, and show/hide controls, but when I close the file, the next time I open it those controls are missing.

I read on another site that there's just no way to get them back. The discussion on that site claimed that after those controls disappear you have to change the code manually (calculate your own percentages, clear floats, etc.). Is this true? There must be a way to get the controls back! ...or at least I really hope there is ;)

Thanks - isa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the *Fluid Grid Layout*, make sure, to save all the files related to that *Fluid Grid Layout* in the same location.

To save a broken *Fluid Grid Layout*, make a new *Fluid Grid Layout*, and save it, then copy and paste the code from the old *Fluid Grid Layout* to the new.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found out a fix to this problem. I was having similar issues in the early stages of coding my website, when the Div handle controls went missing. Then I remembered that right before it went missing, I deleted the extra curly brackets ( that looks like this `}`) at the end of each `@Media Query` (right before the comment):

```
/* Tablet Layout: 481px to 768px. Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout. */
```

I then added back the curly brackets `}` and the Div control handles reappeared. Even to this day I am still able to use the handles, they never disappeared again (unless I disturb the width values (which shouldn't be done, since Fluid Grid Layouts are already pre setup for us.)). And this happened a while back.

The controls disappear when something gets shift within the code or CSS. They never just leave for no reason.